# Possible To Use Insert Query In Fetch Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fetch

I am not sure why this hasn't been answered yet will not that I know of, I am wondering if it's possible to add a insert query with in a while loop I have tried,
but it keeps inserting the comment more then it should (say if it finds 4 status updates it will post the comment in the database 4 times)

I know I have the insert query twice this is not the problem as I had the query where it submits a comment to the database the current query is there for testing purposes.

```
<?php
require_once ("core/connection.php");
require_once ("core/group_functions.php");



   //We need to post the message update in to the database
if(isset($mybb->input['post_message_submit'])) {
$post_message_submit = $mybb->input['post_message_submit'];
$post_message = $mybb->input['post_message'];
$comment_post = $mybb->input['comment_post'];
   if(($post_message_submit) && ($post_message)) {


    $insert_query = $db->query("INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_posts" . "(posted_by, group_name, post_body)
VALUES ('$mybb_username', '$get_group_url' ,'$post_message')");


   } else {
   echo "<text style='color:red;'> You Must Specify A Message</a></text>";
   }
   }



echo "
   <form action='' method='POST'>
<textarea name='post_message' id='post_message' placeholder='Whats Going On?'></textarea><br> 
      <input type='submit' name='post_message_submit' value='Post'>
      </form>

";


$fetch_index_query = $db->query("SELECT post_id,posted_by,post_body,post_active,group_name FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_posts WHERE group_name='$get_group_url'");





while($fetch_index_groups_array = $db->fetch_array($fetch_index_query)) {
$post_id_row = $fetch_index_groups_array['post_id'];
$posted_by = $fetch_index_groups_array['posted_by'];
$g_name = $_fetch_index_groups_array['g_name'];
$g_body = $fetch_index_groups_array['post_body'];
echo"<br>" . "<a href=''> $posted_by </a>" . "<br>" . $gname
. "<br>____________";


$fetch_comments_query = $db->query("SELECT g_name,post_body,comment_by FROM spud_groups_comments WHERE post_id='$post_id_row'");
while($fetch_groups_comments = $db->fetch_array($fetch_comments_query)) {
$post_body = $fetch_groups_comments['post_body'];
echo ("<br>" . $post_body);




}

$insert_query2 = $db->query("INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . "groups_comments" . "(comment_by, post_id, post_body)
VALUES ('$mybb_username', '$post_id_row' ,'$comment_post')");




echo "<br> 
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='comment_post' placeholder='Comment then Hit Enter'>
</form>
";





}

//We have done everything we need to do we can now exit and not execute anything beyond this point
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate other $DB object for the insert query. i.e. do not use the same one you are using to fetch the array, as the next use will overwrite the result of the first query that you are looping through.

Comment: the second insert query is for inserting the comment in the database like I have said the query in the while loop is going to be used to insert the comment in the database..